# intel MKL pardiso won't run parallel in fortran

Tags: multithreading, fortran, intel-mkl, pardiso

I am trying to get the intel MKL version of pardiso to work with multiple cores. Im using it to solve a structurally symmetric system (`mtype=1`) with around 60K equations.

```
  iparm= 0
  iparm(1) = 1 !
  iparm(2) = 3 !  
  iparm(3) = omp_get_max_threads() !   
  iparm(4) = 0 !
  iparm(5) = 0 !
  iparm(6) = 0 !
  iparm(7) = 0 !
  iparm(8) = 9 ! 
  iparm(9) = 0 !
  iparm(10) = 13
  iparm(11) = 1 
  iparm(12) = 0 
  iparm(13) = 0 
  iparm(14) = 0 
  iparm(15) = 0 
  iparm(16) = 0 
  iparm(17) = 0 
  iparm(18) = -1
  iparm(19) = -1
  iparm(20) = 0
```

These are the my `ipram` parameters. When compiling I have

```
F90FLAGS = ${F77FLAGS} -I${SOLIDroot} -openmp -mkl=parallel -d-lines -debug
```

Before calling pardiso I also set the number of threads available to MKL and openmp

`call mkl_set_num_threads(3)
call omp_set_num_threads(3)`

```
call mkl_set_dynamic(0) ! disabling dynamic adjustment of the number of threads
```

As far as I have understood, all MKL functions will try to use multiple threads if allowed or enabled for "sufficiently" large problems. I already have some parallelism using OMP and the code runs on several cores. The region from which I call pardiso is serial. My question is, what else is needed to make pardiso work with multiple cores?

Tried with the default values for `iparm`, ie `iparm(1)=0` and there was no change

Comment: Post full code please.

Comment: You should check your `iparm` array. This array has 64 entries (not only 20) and `iparm(3)` is reserved and should be zero. Did you try to run with default values (`iparm(1) = 0`)?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot add a comment (not enough reputations).

You can try setting the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS before you run the code and see if that works.